# Doubts while practicing gayatri mantra

Tags: meditation, gayatri-mantra, vedic-chanting

I am facing the below questions in my mind while chanting Gayatri mantra. Can anyone please help me to unblock these doubts or questions?

1. When we spell the Gayatri mantra with sound, it produces a frequency of waves which is helpful to cure some problems like Depression, stress, and others. Will it create the same effect if we do it in mind?
2. While chanting the gayatri mantra in mind, do we need to remember the meaning of each word?
3. How many breaks we need to give in the Gayatri mantra to ease to remember the meaning of the mantra and also chanting of mantra? I mean like can we give 5 breaks as "Om" | "bhur buvah swah" | "tat savitur varenyam" | "bhargo devasya dimahi" | "Dhiyo yo nah prachodayat"
4. How to control breathing during the Gayatri mantra-like when to inhale, exhale and hold the breathe?

Comment: You need to be a traivarnika with upanayanam to recite gayatri mantra. Have you done it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it can create harmful effects if done wrong for long periods of time, There are some ways to chant it, I guess the Sanskrit channel on youtube is going to be quite helpful; should you not have access to initiation by a formal guru.

Comment: I would suggest you should read this book on Gayatri Sadhana by Om Swami : https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43836984-the-hidden-power-of-gayatri-mantra

Comment: @ikshvaku yes, I am  yajurvedi.. I am practicing gayatri mantra more than 15 years.. Now I want to go deeper into it.. So trying to clarify these doubts

Comment: @just_do_it I completed this book.. I also daily going through lots of videos, papers on Gayatri mantra to find my answers